# define a prop type as a single number or array of numbers based on another prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, conditional-types

Here is a simple example of what I am looking for. I am implementing an array and I want to check if the multi prop is true, type of items should be number[]. Otherwise, set the type to number.

```
interface EnhancedSelectProps {
  items: multi ? number[] : number;
  multi?: boolean;
}

const EnhancedSelect = ({
  items,
  multi,
}: EnhancedSelectProps) => {}
```

I have tried the union type but it is not working.
when I want to do something like this, it will give me a ts error.

```
interface EnhancedSelectProps {
  items?: number[] | number;
  multi?: boolean;
}

const EnhancedSelect = ({
  items,
  multi,
}: EnhancedSelectProps) => {
  if(multi) console.log(items.length);
    else console.log(items)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use a discriminated union, discriminated on the `multi` field:

```
type EnhancedSelectProps = {
  items?: number[];
  multi: true;
} | {
  multi: false; 
  items?: number;
}

const EnhancedSelect = ({
  items,
  multi,
}: EnhancedSelectProps) => {
  if(multi) console.log(items?.length);
    else console.log(items)
}
EnhancedSelect({ multi: true, items: [1,2]})
EnhancedSelect({ multi: true, items: 1}) // error
EnhancedSelect({ multi: false, items: [1,2]}) // error
EnhancedSelect({ multi: false, items: 1}) 
EnhancedSelect({ items: [1,2]}) // error
EnhancedSelect({ items: 1 })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgCwIZwMYQCYGUIBsKrAAKATgPZgDOUAvFAN4CwAUFFAJbAQC2lA-AC4ocAK7cARhBIBtALoBuFm24jcwdkOAkRERcwC+UAD4MlUFWvaCoAMyS5KuqGc49+Q0RKl79LFqjI4SmBYRBR0bDwCELoACiZWDi5eABozC3U0gyF4ZDRMHHxCUgpKAEpaAD5TRPYbWIz2CoCgsnwAOlwyAHNY114+Tog4buAEMr02NjxHKBbKNohOnr7k8pZfZlzwgqjCePNVdU1tCBSktyFpAEYUgCZZfTKWbfzIouADxpOdc-7KITXJ5QAD0IKgUnIJBeYTehWiXyOGls9kcfzWV1uD2BYIhJChMLyEXh+3oh0sQjsDjOF14gOBhJ27wRZP+mPujwquMhZGhW1hxL2n1ZGKg1ygwKAA)

If you are  using an older version of Typescript (<= 4.6), you can't destructure the parameter and still have TS understand the relationship between the fields, you will need to wither use the parameter itself or destructure after the check:

```
const EnhancedSelect = (p: EnhancedSelectProps) => {
  if(p.multi) {
    console.log(p.items?.length);
    const { items } = p
    console.log(items?.length);
  } else {
    console.log(p.items)
    const { items } = p
    console.log(items)
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgCwIZwMYQCYGUIBsKrAAKATgPZgDOUAvFAN4CwAUFFAJbAQC2lA-AC4ocAK7cARhBIBtALoBuFm24jcwdkOAkRERcwC+UAD4MlUFWvaCoAMyS5KuqGc49+Q0RKl79LFqjI4SmBYRBR0bDwCELoACjAheGQ0TBx8QlIKSgBKWgA+U1YOG3iAOgt1XKYitgCgsnxS3DIAczLXXj4miDgW4ARsvTZawOCGDi5eKEM6MDMR+sbmto7+bt7+wbNDPEdC4ag6ygaIJtb2yZz5w9GQ+gm3adooOZqbxdPl2NXs7ZZ9IA)

Comment: I did the same thing but still get these errors.
multi ? `${selected?.length} items` : selected?.label
1-Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ISelect | ISelect[]' 
2-Property 'label' does not exist on type 'ISelect | ISelect[]'

Comment: @Sky The code sample I posted works. If you are on an older version of TypeScript  (4.6 and below), the compiler won't be able to follow that the destructured parameters are entangled and you would need to destructure after the check: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgCwIZwMYQCYGUIBsKrAAKATgPZgDOUAvFAN4CwAUFFAJbAQC2lA-AC4ocAK7cARhBIBtALoBuFm24jcwdkOAkRERcwC+UAD4MlUFWvaCoAMyS5KuqGc49+Q0RKl79LFqjI4SmBYRBR0bDwCELoACjAheGQ0TBx8QlIKSgBKWgA+U1YOG3iAOgt1XKYitgCgkPoOLl4oQzowM1rAyjJ8UtwyAHNY114+fog4QeAEbL02QzxHQrYu+oYmt1baKA6aqDqevoHh0ZyzXwMgA

Comment: apparently I have this version of ts. "typescript": "^4.5.4"

Comment: @Sky Updated the answer for older versions

Answer (score 1):

Titian beat me to it but here is a version using generics

```
interface EnhancedSelectProps<T extends boolean> {
    items: T extends false ? number : number[];
    multi?: T;
}

function EnhancedSelect({
    items,
    multi,
}: EnhancedSelectProps<true> | EnhancedSelectProps<false>) {
    if (multi) console.log(items.length);
    else console.log(items)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgBZxEgJgZQgBsIEwAFKAewAcBnAHgBVkIAPSEXO5AIyqolsAPmQBvAFDJpyYJAC2dAFzIW7Tt2TwidFAH5kIAK7ze0ZCuOnoAbQC6Abikz5RomGB6VTJwF8JEjBGOB5UIGiY2HiEJGQAFJIysgp0ADTO0q7uwOm+KuhYOBAExKQU1PQMYFBGEKIAPhGF0aVklLSM2rrCAJTiGbIwyHFZHn0IYXSCEAB0RFQA5nFyEIpzECALYBg9TknEusgTIFMkc4vLKT0S-hIFUcUxZQnJq8rINgCMqcgATD8AZjsP1GwBUXRQvj6AHpoWgoNQoHdIkUSrEwC8VooVF8fv9kECQW4PCpqrVkFDkLDkAB5ADWyOaj1aGLEr2xH2+f0BdgpMLh9MZDzRzzZWPen1+AKJ2VJNUh-PhiKFqKe8TFKRUkulyFB4LgOgVVIFdKAA)

Comment: seems it is not working.

Comment: same error like Titian answer

Comment: @Sky what version of TS are you using? Did you check the playground? It works as expected there